# How to stream parquet directly from SQL to S3 using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, parquet

I am getting a result from SQL and using C# writing it to a local temp parquet file on disk before uploading to S3.

I am using the parquet.net library as well as all the standard AWS packages for s3 (AWSSDK.S3 I believe)

Please excuse the certain areas where I just left pseudocode but this is the basic structure... I want to be able to stream the rows directly to S3 instead of writing the file locally first.

Thanks in advance.

```
using (var parquetWriter = new ParquetWriter(parquetSchema, fileStream))
{
    var parquetTable = new Parquet.Data.Rows.Table(parquetSchema);
    foreach(object[] data in dataset)
    {
         //prepare data for parquet schema here

         parquetTable.Add(data);
         if (parquettablesize >= number of rows I want to write at one time)
         {
              parquetWriter.Write(parquetTable);
              parquetTable = new Parquet.Data.Rows.Table(parquetSchema); //cant reuse the same object
         }
    }

    // write whatever is left here
    if (parquetTable.Count > 0)
          parquetWriter.Write(parquetTable);


    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
         //upload the file to my S3 location
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to solve a similar problem some time ago but could not find any clean and easy solutions. Intermediate file or memory stream is the way to go. Minimal code and the least possibility to screw something up.

Comment: @OptionalOption that is unfortunate...